# skipping "self" keyword for a member variable crashes the program

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In the code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Browny", @"Andy", @"Chiki", @"Gillu",
                      @"SnowLeopard", @"Lion", @"Tiger", @"SiberianTiger", nil ];
    self.pickerData = array;
    [array release];    

}
```

if I change in above `self.pickerData` to `pickerData`, the program crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received`.

I thought for member variables/properties of the object using keyword `self` was optional?
Any hints, why I need `self` here, even though `pickerData` is a member variable of the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To wrap it up in one answer instead of dotted across the other answers.

When you call

```
self.pickerData = array;
```

this is compiled to

```
[self setPickerData:array];
```

If you `@sythesize` `pickerData` the implementation will do something similar to:

```
- (void)setPickerData:(NSArray *)_pickerData;
{
    if (pickerData != _pickerData) {
        [pickerData release];
        pickerData = [_pickerData retain];
    }
}
```

So the difference is that `self.pickerData = array` will go through the setter that will do the correct memory management whereas `pickerData = array` assigns the value directly.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because when you do `self.something = value`, a `retain` is called for *value*. When you remove *self*, it will not retain, and as you are releasing the variable *array* just before the method returns, the "pickerData" will point to a invalid memory location.

So, you must keep *self*, or manually retain it, like `pickerData = [array retain];`

Comment: But what *characteristic* of `pickerData` is the cause?

Comment: self.pickerData = array; is *precisely* equivalent to [self setPickerData: array];. So the difference is the implementation of -setPickerData:, whether that be via synthesized property or your own implementation.

Comment: it is already retained, being an init/alloc, you just need not release if you aren't using the property, but you would leak the old array if pickerData pointed to something.

Answer (score 0):

`self.pickerData = array;` 
is the same as `[self setPickerData:array]` which if your property is declared with retain is something like:

```
-(void)setPickerData:(NSArray *)_pickerData
{
    id t = pickerData;
    pickerData = [_pickerData retain];
    [t release];
}
```

in your example without the property, you end up releasing the array right after, but the iVar pickerData still points to it, the next time you try yo use it you will very likely crash.

Comment: The problem is when you use the setter to set the value of the object to the same value again, i.e. if `_pickerData==pickerData`. Then you would first release the object and retain it afterwards. If the release count of the `pickerData` is 1 at that time, the object will be deallocated after the release, and then the code tries to retain an object that doesn't exist any more.

Comment: but I do see the problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers indicate, the `self.property` construct is much more than simple syntax (it invokes setter and getter methods).

However, the synthesized getters just return the underlying ivar, so in right hand side expressions, you can in practice use synthesized getters or ivars interchangeably.

Personally, I prefer to use the same style of access of both left hand side and right hand side expressions, so once I use setters, I also try to use getters throughout. But that is a matter of style and personal taste, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

When the following codes were executed :

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Browny", @"Andy", @"Chiki", @"Gillu",
                      @"SnowLeopard", @"Lion", @"Tiger", @"SiberianTiger", nil ];
```

the retain count of `array` will be 1.

If you choose to use `self.pickerData = array;` because of the setter method, the retain count of array will be 2. Then, after executing `[array release];` the retain count of array will be 1 again, it is retained be pickerData.

However, if `pickerData = array` is used, array's retain count will still be 1, since no `retain` were executed. Therefore, after `[array release];`, pickerData's retain count will become 0 whereas pickerData is still using. Therefore a crash.

I think @Paul.s has addressed a fairly great answer, the key point is that the setter method is different when a key word `self` is used. I hereby answer it in another prospective, hoping it could be helpful and more plain.